# Get count of a specific pattern from many files on HDFS and store in a file on HDFS using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

I have a directory on HDFS which will have a lot of files.
I want to count the occurence of a particular text, something like ABCDEF from all the files. I am able to count the total number of lines in all the files, but cant
get the pattern count of "ABCDEF" from them.
I am using spark job in java for counting lines.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("LineCount").getOrCreate();
JavaRDD<String> lines = spark.read().textFile(args).javaRDD();
LOGGER.info("Total number of lines {} ", Long.valueOf(lines.count()));
```

I am also not able to save this count in a file on HDFS. I tried:

```
Path path=new Path("hdfs://10.1.2.3:9000/test/directory");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(path,true)));
br.write((int) lines.count());
br.close();
spark.stop();
```

But it is saving some garbage value to the file on hdfs.

Comment: This resolved my issue. Can save sqlDF asTextFile on HDFS location now.

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Count").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.json("hdfs://10.1.2.3:9000/test/test.json")
    df.show
    df.select("ID").show()
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("dummy")
    val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM dummy where ID like '%6630404a9%'")
    sqlDF.show()

Comment: But, with default memory, spark was not able to read JSON from HDFS, because of which I had to give more memory to it. 
But, somehow the memory utilization of master node got shot up to max and there was no memory left for any java processes to run. 
I had to stop spark daemons because of that (which resolved the java issue). I would have given too much memory to spark processes. 
What is the way through which one can optimize the memory allocation for spark?